# Is REST API Polling the best solution?

Tags: rest, polling

**Problem:**

I have a REST API which works as follows:

1. Once a user client clicks on "CHANGE" button on a site, the user is
   redirected to "my" site.
2. Processing starts on my site.
3. User needs
           to login to his email to accept a confirmation link.
4. Once link is confirmed by user my site sends response to original site.
5. Original site, where the CHANGE button was pressed, upon receipt of the
       response from my site sends feedback to the client.

**My solution:**

My site sends "`HTTP 201 Created`" once the user is redirected to my site. My site processes client's information and waits for confirmation link from email to be pressed by client.
This sends a POST request to my server which acknowledges it and sends `HTTP 202 response` accepted to the client.
Client has to poll waiting for the `HTTP 202 response`.

I do not like the client having to poll and keep GETting and waiting for my response. Is there a better solution?

Thanks for your help :)